# ruby access to timesten

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timesten

I googled a lot to find any one has accessed timesten from ruby. I need to access timesten from Ruby (v1.9.3).

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: The only thing I found was people accessing it via jRuby: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=584414

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access Oracle TimesTen via Ruby is via the [ODPI-C](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/) ruby-ODPI SQL driver.

ODPI-C is a c wrapper to OCI and the same Ruby code can be used on TimesTen and the Oracle RDBMS.

You should use tnsnames.ora to define a service name that maps to a TimesTen DSN.

You should use the connection pattern as defined in the [Oracle sample code](https://github.com/kubo/ruby-odpi/blob/master/samples/test_fetch.rb).

Comment: I'd try ruby-oci8 instead of ruby-odpi, since the former is being regularly updated. be warned:  I don't know what limitations it will have against TimesTen.